# Fedora Gnome black screen after boot

Tags: fedora, gnome, nvidia

The issue is pretty consistent, almost every time when I boot I see black screen.
I found 2 simple workarounds:

1. press "Sleep" button and then immediately wake the PC up
2. press Ctrl + Alt + F3 to switch to console-mode and then Ctrl + Alt + F1 to switch back to GUI

Then login screen appears as it should.

What can be the issue and how to fix it?
P.S.: I use official NVIDIA driver instead of Nouveau.